# Show drafts via command-line remote call

Tags: gerrit

I can get a list of projects with this command:

```
ssh -p 29418 ***.***.***.com gerrit ls-projects
```

Is there a way I can get a **list of drafts** in a similar fashion?

I didn't see a way after reviewing their documentation: https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-index.html

Also, I would prefer to not use:

```
git review --list
```

I'm looking for a native gerrit approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about draft *changes* you're probably looking for the [is:draft search operator](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#is) for the [query SSH command](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html):

```
ssh ... gerrit query is:draft
```

If you're interested in changes with draft *comments* use [has:draft](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#has) instead.